# Find Min Max Values for consecutive Series in a Column when the series changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table consists of 3 columns: Time, Tagid, and Intvalue with millions or rows.
I would like to find min and max values of the Intvalue column when the row data of the Intvalue change from hi to low.

How do you write a SQL query to get the following results:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.  Assuming o ties, you can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(intvalue) over (partition by tagid order by time) as prev_iv,
             lead(intvalue) over (partition by tagid order by time) as next_iv
      from t
     ) t
where prev_intvalue is null or
      next_intvalue is null or
      (intvalue > prev_intvalue and intvalu > next_intvalue)
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I made a slight modification:select *
From (
  SELECT  DATEADD(HH,-5,DATEADD(s,t_stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00')) as Time,[tagid]
     ,[intvalue]
     -- ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp) AS rn
      ,lag(intvalue) over (partition by tagid order by t_stamp) as prev_iv,
      lead(intvalue) over (partition by tagid order by t_stamp) as next_iv
    FROM [IgnHistorianDB].[dbo].[sqlt_data_5_2019_02]
    where tagid=353
 ) t   
Where 
    prev_iv is null or
       next_iv is null or
      (intvalue > prev_iv and intvalue> next_iv)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query.

```
Select *
From (
        SELECT  DATEADD(HH,-5,DATEADD(s,t_stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00')) as Time,[tagid]
              ,[intvalue]
              -- ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp) AS rn
               ,lag(intvalue) over (partition by tagid order by t_stamp) as prev_iv,
               lead(intvalue) over (partition by tagid order by t_stamp) as next_iv
          FROM [IgnHistorianDB].[dbo].[sqlt_data_5_2019_02]
          where tagid=353
    ) t   
Where 
       prev_iv is null or
       next_iv is null or
      (intvalue > prev_iv and intvalue> next_iv)
```